# How to handle 'dict' object has no attribute 'META'?

Tags: python, json, django, django-views

I'm trying to create a JSON response in a django project; but something goes wrong!

````
applications_list = []
for project in projects_list:
    application_information = {
        ``` some keys and values ```
    }
    applications_list.append(application_information)
context = {'applications': applications_list}

return render(request, self.template_name, context)
````

But I got this error:

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'META'
```

Should be mentioned that keys and values of `application_information` are serialized. I also tried `json.dumps()` but didn't work.
I wonder what have been missed?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you accidentally modified the `request` variable before you passed it to `render` call.

Check what happens with that variable in the code before the snippet you posted, or expand your question with additional code lines.